# failed to load resource

Tags: jquery, media

Im trying to set up a simple mp3 player:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{         
    $('a.media').media( { width: 300, height: 20 } );                      
});
</script>
```

and then

```
<a class="media" href="piano.mp3">piano</a>
```

But i get the following error: `Failed to load resource`

I have followed the tutorial at http://jquery.malsup.com/media/audio.html, and if i click to view source and clikc on piano.mp3 chrome opens up its built in media player and plays the song, so the link and location is correct...

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you probably need to download mediaplayer.swf since it's the default player for mp3 files (according to the docs)

Comment: ahhh... common! couldnt he atleast post a little notic about that? Or maybe i should have read the doc :P but yeah, googled and found the mediaplayer.swf. problem solved. ty ty!